# execute a jsp program on background of a running java program

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I just want execute my jsp program when a button on my running java program is clicked, it doesn't need to be visible, the jsp program i am saying is for printing and once it is loaded in the browser it will just pop up the print dialog confirm box, so again it doesn't need to be visible, once the button in my java program is clicked the print dialog will just pop up and that's it. By the way i am new here in this site, and also know only basics of java, so i do not have any idea how to do it, but i like to do it that way and with just a link of the jsp page from the localhost, something like that,

Thanks in advance buddies! Hope you will help me!...

Comment: your java program is a web application , right ??

Comment: no,it's planned to be a desktop application.Also helping me with printing problems can resolve my problem,thanks

Comment: in a desktop application , where do you put the JSP Page

Comment: inside my localhost,i have already done a jsp program and its running,and now i am developing in java with the same module,so what i want to happen now is like importing/hyper-linking my jsp module for printing because i am having a bad time doing it on java because i am only a beginner on it,thanks dude.

Comment: use something like javascript or jquery inside your jsp program to do it

Comment: i am done with my jsp,it can print on load and its working,after loading the page it will immediately pop up the print dialog,so what i want to do is import/hyperlink my working jsp printing script to the java program that i am developing,without loading the browser for my jsp script,just pop up the print dialog box,is that posible?,thanks...

Comment: you want all the data from your jsp to be passes in your java program , like the complete page to be passed to the java program , is that right ??

Comment: actually not that much,i just want the jsp page to print/execute my printing script;just execute/call the jsp script so it will print,and it will be triggered by a button on my java program,most likely i want to done that by the use on the jsp localhost link only if thats posible.

Answer (score 0):

this should be working , cant be sure if it serves properly , please assure me the outcome

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


    public class callURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/OpenID/asd.html";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
        try 
        {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            char[] buf = new char[8000];
            int l = 0;
                while (l >= 0) 
                {
                    builder.append(buf, 0, l);
                    l = in.read(buf);
                }

        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

for this java program to ececute your jsp

you have to add this line in your jsp page

```
<script>
window.location.href="http://localhost:8080/OpenID/asd.html"
</script>

where OpenId : Application Name
asd.html is your jsp page , the same jsp which you are calling from java program
```

Comment: thanks dude,your code works with no error,but it does not execute the jsp script,go to debug when executing it says 
"Class File not Found
source not found" and show the button of change attach source

/  (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class java.net.URLClassLoader extends java.security.SecureClassLoader {
  
  // Field descriptor #208 Lsun/misc/URLClassPath;
  sun.misc.URLClassPath ucp;
  
  // Field descriptor #206 Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;
  private java.security.AccessControlContext acc;

Comment: I think the code were near,i just change the http://localhost:8080 to something like "http://localhost:8080/foldername/pagename.jsp" , when i loaded the page in the browser it pop ups the print dialog and it will print immediately,that's what i would like to happen,something like that,thank you for helping me,i really need it,i hope we can do it,thanks again,i will wait for you're reply...

Comment: actually it's not working at me, the page doesn't execute, but i think the concept is correct and it's near to exact answer, by the way is it working to you? 

try to save it as html page in your desktop and execute it using the java program, i think it has the same concept, thanks in advance buddy, i really need it,thanks again!..

<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
 alert("page executed!");
</script>
</body>
<html>

Comment: call bounty on the question

Comment: @user2006107 : i have made an edit , see this , it solves your problem

Comment: thanks again dude,it doesn't have error in the console but there is a message in the debug here it is 
"<terminated>callURL [Java Application] 
 <terminated, exit value: 0>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (Jan 28, 2013 9:49:45 AM)"

can i ask what is happening when you run s code in your system?,i think i am just missing something,and your code is very near to it,here is mt html code:
<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<script>
 alert("got it!");
</script>
<script>
window.location.href="http://localhost:8080/ERP/asd.html"
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
thanks again dude...

Comment: actually for once it executed for me but again i am having the same prob that it goes in the infinite loop of redirection , will tell you if I find another solution

Comment: thanks a lot men i will wait it,i think we can just make the html code like this

`code`
<html> <title></title> <head></head> <script> alert("got it!"); </script> <body></body> </html>
`code`

actually i just like the page to show the print dialog,i think it has the same concept in alert message,thank you again dude!..

Comment: i find something i get a code that can open the URL but the browser will open also,now as a substitute i want the web page to close after i loads the print script,i have done my searching but still didn't find the correct answer/code it, i really need to make it, thank you again buddy,by the way here is the code 

`code`
 try { Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start google.com"); } catch(IOException e1) {System.out.println(e1);} } } `code`