# How to execute a JSP program using a Java program without opening a web browser?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, printing, header

The JSP script I want to execute is for printing purposes. When executed it pops up a print dialog. That is what I want to do in my java program. When the button on the Java GUI is clicked the print dialog of the JSP page will just pop up without opening the browser, that's what I would like to happen.

Another option I just need to know other way on printing using java program, I just how to print the whole panel, but now I am having problem when it comes to printing with more than 1 page. How can I put header in every print page? Something like that, and can I put another JPanel inside a JPanel, and how? By the way I am new here in the site and also in Java programming.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is too vauge and broad in nature.  JSP executes on a server.  Maybe you mean to use javascript?

Comment: You say `when the button on the java GUI is clicked` which makes this sound like a Java Desktop GUI program, not a Web Application. JSP is used within servlet containers like Tomcat or jBoss to dynamically create web pages. JSP isn't intended for use in desktop programs.

Comment: @StephenP yes you are right, i am just thinking if it is possible to execute a jsp program in java, someone answer me that maybe it possible here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493601/execute-a-jsp-program-on-background-of-a-running-java-program , thanks for your help, or maybe you could teach me a way on printing using java especially with multiple pages, by the way i am not a expert in java programming, thank you in advance!

Comment: A properly designed JSP file is intented to generate HTML, not to invoke some business actions. Perhaps you're either facing a very legacy JSP file with all raw Java code embedded in `<% %>` things, or you're confusing JavaScript (the Java look-a-like language in HTML `<script>` elements) with Java. E.g. `window.print()` is pure JavaScript. You don't "just" execute that from a desktop application without a web server and web browser. You should be looking for a pure Java solution to print. Start with `javax.print.*`. I recommend to reframe your question and omit the irrelevant JSP/Servlet part

Comment: so you asked the same question again ??

Answer (score 0):

A *.jsp is a template for the server side processing of an http request.
The result of the processing is an html web page returned as an http response to the client.

Some IDEs, for example Eclipse let you preview a *.jsp page.
But this is a basic preview of the page, the actual page may look very different.

The best way to preview a web page it to actually view it.

There are free, lightweight web servers available for download, they can be easily integrated in most of modern IDEs. There should be no problem with installing your war and viewing the actual page on one of such servers.

Comment: so it is not possible?,thanks for you're reply man.

i just like to ask a question, how to print the whole JPanel even though it is not visible on the JFrame or JPanel, i have working script now on how to print the whole JPanel, but i am having trouble now when i am printing more than one page, it only print one page maybe because the lower side is not visible, but i think it should print, because i set an exceed height maybe it's not visible on the monitor but it should be right there in the frame, sorry for my bad explanation,hope you got me, thanks again man...

Comment: @user2006107 Wait. Are you writing a Swing application? If so, it has nothing in common with *.jsp. It's a GUI library. Oh, I see the guys already explained it. Sorry, my answer is odd, probably in this context.

Comment: @user2006107 I think you should tag your question as Java, Swing. And directly ask something like "how ...JFrame or JPanel...in a Swing application".

Comment: ok now i get it is not possible i thought it is because someone replies me in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493601/execute-a-jsp-program-on-background-of-a-running-java-program, and i thought the idea can do it. @Alex, now my new question is how can i print the whole JPanel even though its height is more than one page and some of its part is not user visible because of the monitor/screen size,i can now print the Jpanel,but it's always one page, i think i am missing something, hope you can help me, sorry im just new in this site and a beginner in java, thank you buddies.